# Whats the most pythonic way to calculate percentage changes on a list of numbers

Tags: python

I have a list of floating point numbers and I want to generate another list of period returns from my first list.

This is a run of the mill implementation (not tested - and OBVIOUSLY no error checking/handling):

```
a = [100,105,100,95,100]

def calc_period_returns(values, period):
    output = []
    startpos, endpos = (period, len(values)-1)

    while True:
        current = values[startpos]
        previous = values[startpos-period]
        ret = 100*((current-previous)/(1.0*previous))
        output.append(ret)
        startpos += period
        if startpos > endpos:
            break
    return output


calc_period_returns(a,1)

# Expected output:
# [5.0, -4.7619047619047619, -5.0, 5.2631578947368416]
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this - perhaps using list comprehension and maps?

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk: I have updated the question with an expected output

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: Your code is buggy. If you wan't us to give any definite solution, please explain how your output is calculated.

Comment: my bad, snippet was too buggy. I corrected it now.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: Now your Expected O/P is not matching with the O/P from your code

Comment: Gah! code is still buggy. ok, gimme a little while to sort out wtf is going wrong. This should be simple SMDH. OK done. I'll edit the expected output to reflect the new values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> [100.0 * a1 / a2 - 100 for a1, a2 in zip(a[1:], a)]
[5.0, -4.7619047619047592, -5.0, 5.2631578947368354]
```

Since you want to compare neighbor elements of a list, you better create a list of pairs you are interested in, like this:

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> zip(a, a[1:])
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

After that it is just a simple math to extract a percentage change from a pair of numbers.

Comment: Were you aware of this Terminology or you deciphered from his code?

Comment: @Abhijit slightly:)  Just mapped input to output:)

Comment: Just a smal FYI, this fails with division by zero if any of the numbers is zero.

Answer (score 22):

I don't know how large your list of numbers is going to be, but if you are going to process large amounts of numbers, you should have a look at numpy. The side effect is that calculations look a lot simpler.

With numpy, you create an array for your data

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([100,105,100,95,100], dtype=float)
```

and work with arrays as if they were simple numbers

```
>>> np.diff(a) / a[:-1] * 100.
[ 5.         -4.76190476 -5.          5.26315789]
```

Comment: Actually, what you really want is `np.diff(a) / np.abs(a[:-1]) * 100.`. Furthermore, an item in a could be 0, so to avoid divide by 0 error you may want to do  something like `a[a == 0] = 0.000000001`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer guys! A function I implemented based on your answers if someone just wanna copy paste (like me):

```
def pct_change(nparray):
    pct=np.zeros_like(nparray)
    pct[1:]=np.diff(nparray) / np.abs(nparray[:-1])
    #TODO zero divisionerror
    return pct
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also to this:

```
>>> a = [100,105,100,95,100]
>>> [(a[i]-a[i-1])/a[i-1] for i in range(1, len(a))]
[0.05, -0.047619047619047616, -0.05, 0.05263157894736842]
```